# create some sort of loop inside linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that I want to use to filter a listview. I am creating the listview dynamically therfore I don't know the number of colums in advance. lstCurrentDynamicItems is a class with just one property and that property is named c and its type is object[]. I created that class in order to hold objects of the listview. If I always would have the same listview then I would have no problem building the following method. How could I implement the following method?

```
public void filterListView(string[] columnsContains)
        {
            // lstCurrentDynamicItems is a list of objects
            // columnsContains is what I want to filter.             
            var qr = from a in lstCurrentDynamicItems
                     where a.c[0].ToString().Contains(columnsContains[0]) &&
                           a.c[1].ToString().Contains(columnsContains[1]) &&
                           a.c[2].ToString().Contains(columnsContains[2]) &&
                           //    ...
                           //    ...
                           //    ...
                           a.c[columnsContains.Length].ToString().Contains(columnsContains[columnsContains.Length])                            
                    select a;

            listView.DataContext = qr;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var qr = 
from a in lstCurrentDynamicItems
where Enumerable.Range(0,columnsContains.Length)
                .All(i => a.c[i].ToString().Contains(columnsContains[i]))
select a;
```

Comment: @Tono Nam: of course you must assure that `a.c.Length` is always equal to (or greater than) `columnsContains.Length`

Answer (score 1):

```
var qr = from a in lstCurrentDynamicItems
         where a.c.Select((item, index) => new { item, index }).
                   All(o => o.item.ToString().Contains(columnsContains[o.index]))
         select a;
```

The difference between this and @digEmAll's answer is that his solution will fail if `columnContains` has more elements than the `c` collection, while this solution, on the other hand, will fail if `columnContains` has less elements than the `c` collection.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use for [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx)

```
var qr = from a in lstCurrentDynamicItems
   where c
      .Zip(columnsContains, (a, b) => a.ToString().Contains(b))
      .All(p => p)
   select a;
```

Some of the other methods fail if the sequences do not have equal lengths, but this will always ignore any length mismatch, and only compare the existing elements, no matter which sequence is longer.